# Is "but on what grounds did not appear" ungrammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

You can see the quote beneath on [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=KU5NAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA316&dq=%22but+on+what+grounds+did+not+appear%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAo-n73N_hAhVMVK0KHepxArUQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22but%20on%20what%20grounds%20did%20not%20appear%22&f=false), but I've double-checked it on [Westlaw](http://login.westlaw.co.uk/maf/wluk/ext/app/document?crumb-action=reset&docguid=IABE48A70E42711DA8FC2A0F0355337E9).

The highlighted dependent clause looks wrong to me, as I can't pinpoint the subject of "what did not appear"? "on what grounds" is a prepositional phrase functioning as an adverbial adjunct.

> [image]

Comment: It's court stenographerish for "but the reason for this was not specified."

Comment: Is it bothering you that *on what grounds* appears to be acting as the subject of *did not appear*?  Would you prefer that it were *the grounds for which did not appear* or *whose grounds did not appear*?

Comment: Or perhaps it's not *on what grounds* that bothers you. Maybe you think it should be *but on what grounds* ***was not stated***?

Comment: @tchrist Yes to both questions! Thanks for reading my mind.

Comment: @JasonBassford Your rewrite is grammatical and doesn't bother me, but Kay J's "did not appear" is ungrammatical to me.

Comment: What if I were to say *but on what grounds did not appear in court*?

Comment: @JasonBassford "but on what grounds did not appear in court" feels ungrammatical.

Comment: The reason [for the petition being refused] was not made apparent in court.

Comment: This is quite an interesting question, actually. My gut instinct aligns with the asker’s: “but on what grounds did not appear” is at least borderline ungrammatical (and very garden pathy), whereas “but on what grounds was not stated” is more acceptable (though still, I would say, quite awkwards). I suspect this may be because the plural _grounds_ and the singular _was_ clash so explicitly, so there’s less risk of garden pathiness, but I’m not sure.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is perfectly grammatical. If you read the whole paragraph, Oliver filed with the court (presented) a petition for appointment of new trustees of the testator‘s will. This (referring to the petition) was opposed (resisted) by Ray & Bush, but the grounds for opposing the petition did not appear (were‘t stated in anything Ray & Bush filed with the court in opposition). Nonetheless, the petition was denied. So “on what grounds” refers back to the petition for appointment of the new trustees.

Answer (score 1):

**Paraphrase**

The petition was resisted but the grounds for resisting it were not provided.

Answer (score 0):

A modern, more ordinary (but less pithy) phrasing would be "the grounds in support (of the resistance to the petition) were not presented to us (for consideration or scrutiny)".

"Grounds" is used in the sense of "a set of one or more reasons comprising a justification (of or for something)".

"Appear" is used in the sense of "move or arrive within view (of a particular person)".